# Настройки application.ini приложения ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Добрый день.

Достался мне в наследство сайт на ZendFramework. Часть сайта лежит в папке `/cms/application/`, тут конфиги всякие и папка `/modules/`, часть - в папке `/site/`, тут тоже есть modules, settings и пр.

Проблема следующая: модули, которые лежат в первой папке `/cms/appliaction/` (судя по конфигу, это APPLICATION_PATH), обрабатывают ошибки, т.е. ErrorController.php тут работает. А то, что лежит в папке `/site/`, файл ErrorController.php не воспринимает. Файл `application.ini`, лежащий по адресу `/site/settings/application.ini` содержит примерно следующее:

*phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0

phpSettings.display_errors = 0

phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

autoloaderNamespaces.Zen = "Zen"

installed = true

cache_dir = ROOT_PATH "/site/cache/"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/pages/controllers"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory.0 = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory.1 = ROOT_PATH "/site/modules"

resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV

resources.layout.layoutPath.0 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../res/admin/scripts/"

resources.layout.layoutPath.3 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../res/moder/scripts/"

resources.layout.layoutPath.1 = ROOT_PATH "/site/theme/scripts/"

resources.layout.layoutPath.2 = ROOT_PATH "/site/modules/"

resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"

resources.locale.default = "ru_RU"

resources.modules[] = 

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"

resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"*

Параметры подключения к БД я тут не привожу. **Может, сюда нужно что-то дописать, чтобы заработал ErrorController.php?**

P.S. IndexController и AdminController в папке `/site/modules`/ работают для всех модулей, проблема именно с ErrorController. Версия Zend  1.11.11.

**Дополнение:**
Возможно, я ошибаюсь, единственным модуль, где янашёл упоминанеи о 404-й странице, находиться в папке `application/modules/pages/views/scripts/error/error.phtml`. Вставка кода заглючила, поэтому вот вам скриншот http://joxi.ru/GrqMw4GtYwknrz 
Что за **cnf**, я так и не понял. Причём 404 страница появляется при обращении к несуществующему Action модуля Shop, который вообще лежит в папке `/site/modules/shop/` и у него нет `ErrorController.php` и `errpr.phtml`. =( Я в недоумении.

**Дополнение 2:**

Нашёл, где определён **cnf**, это файл `cms/application/Bootstrap.php`.

```
    public function _initConfig() {
    $config = new Zend_Config ( $this->getOptions () );
    Zend_Registry::set ( 'cnf', $config );
}
```

Но мне всё равно непонятно, почему в error.phtml стоит доп. проверка каких-то параметров, и в зависимости от результатов проверки пользователь видит 404-ю ошибку http://joxi.ru/l2ZvyOxfNBqy2J или какую-то другую, типа расширенную информацию. Разве не ErrorController должен это делать (проверять тип ошибки и вызывать то или иное исключение)?

А ещё больше мне непонятно, каким образом, генерируя ошибку из модуля shop (просто запросил несуществующий action), я вижу error.phtml, **описанный в модуле pages** (я ставил вот сюда http://joxi.ru/a2XVkRnSaJ6erg id="111", чтобы убедиться, что вижу error.phtml именно из модуля pages)?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, он будет контроллер Error искать тут:

    APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/pages/controllers

А какую нибудь ошибку пишет?

Comment: нет, ничего не пишет, просто белый экран и пустой html код вместо контента (шапка и подвал грузятся, а посередине ничего).

Comment: так вот здесь:
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

поставьте единички и посмотрите что пишет

Comment: Как ни странно, ничего нет. Поставил единички, как Вы сказали, поставил `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT|E_WARNING);` и `ini_set('display_errors', true);` в файле index.php. Включил показ ошибок в .htaccess. Перегрузил локальный сервер и ничего =(

Comment: Как минимум должен сказать, что такого action нет.

Comment: В общем, у вас во view явно написано, что искать надо в реестре. Установленній флаг cnf->debug, если он не установлен ошибок не выводить. Флаг ищите в bootstrap.php или в конфигах. Но, скорее, он не установлен вообще. Если надо дебаг, так запихните в Zend_Redistry то, что просит на выборку

Comment: И все равно при всех этих манипуляциях у вас должно было выдать хотя бы сообщение о том, что ошибка. Даже если предположить, что cnf === null